# Why does the 74LS08 see an input logic level even if the inputs are not connected?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates, ttl

I have an 74LS08 (AND gate.) I did not connect any inputs to the IC, but it gives me voltage at the outputs. Should I separate VSS?

[image]

[image]

Comment: An unconnected 74-series TTL gate input is at logical *true/high*. (Don't leave C-MOS inputs floating/unconnected.)(What is `VSS`? You should add a bypass capacitor just to get used to doing so.)

Comment: so if it connected in inputs is a logical true/high ?

Comment: If you connect a logic gate input to low/GND, it is *false/low*. The overly prudent way to get a high/true was to *invert* a false/low.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TTL chips (like the LS74xx series) will see a high on any unconnected inputs,  if you want them to see a low connect the inputs to ground

They'll actually put a voltage there, you can measure it with a voltmeter.

Comment: Though good design practice is to not leave an LS input open.  If you really want that to be a logic high, then either drive it or provide a resistive pull up.

Comment: @SteveSh Are 20kOhm enough? That is the nominal value of the internal pull-up according to TI's data sheet of the 74LS08. ;-) Anyway, in a real design I connect unused inputs always to VCC or GND. You never know, the IC might be changed to CMOS one future day.

Comment: We usually use something lower, around 4.7K.  That value makes it look like it was calculated rather than just pulled out of the air <smile>.  Also, it was typical to connect several unused 'LS inputs to a single resistor.